# django update/create view old values

Tags: django, django-generic-views

i have a ModelForm that i use as the form_class for both of the views.

in both cases i need to update a different model before i save the object of

the views. i.e. i use the views to create/update model A and i need to update

model B based on the A object.

my problems are:

1. in the model form i don't know if it create or update in the save method
2. i don't know the old values of the fields in case of an update

anyone know how i can solve this?

update:

```
class updateA(UpdateView):
    model = A
    form_class = AForm

class createA(CreateView):
    model = A
    form_class = AForm

class AForm(ModelForm):
    a = super(AForm, self).save(commit=False)
    if commit:
        a.save()
    return log
```

Comment: could you include some code?

Comment: It's your view method to determine if current action is a create or an update, not the form. I don't understand why you try to look at the `save()` method and determine that.

Comment: how can i get the saved object in the view? or to know the old values of the object if update?

Comment: found it.. in form_valid of the view in the changed_data